# Drawing conclusions from given information about a compact manifold with nonempty boundary that admits CW structure.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am studying for the topology qualifying exam, and I am stuck on this problem from past qualifying exam. Could anyone give me some insight on this problem?

M: compact manifold with nonempty boundary.

We can assume that M admits a CW structure. Then what can we conclude about the space M from each of the following?

(1) $\mathrm{H_m}(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $m\geq 5$.

(2) $\mathrm{H_m}(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $m> 5$. and $\mathrm{H_5}(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)=0$.

(3) $\mathrm{H_m}(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $m> 5$. and $\mathrm{H_5}(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$.

(4) M has dimension two and $\mathrm{H_1}(M, \mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$

Edit: We can assume M is connected.

Comment: Is $M$ connected? (4) implies $M$ is the annulus or Mobius band. That's because $\pi_1(M)$ is free, and hence rank $1$ by the homology condition. Gluing in disks to the boundary components shows we get either the sphere or projective plane.

Comment: @SteveD Yes we can assume M is connected. Thank you very much for your comment.